# Full width layout with Bootstrap 3, but with fluid container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to build a page with 5 sections, with different full width background.

My idea is the following

```
<section id="aboutus">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row>
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

In that case I can add full width background for #aboutus, and the content inside will be 1170px, and centered. The problem is that I have to repeat '.container' many times. What is the best practice for this?

Can I do same with the following code?

```
<div class="container">
    <section id="aboutus">
        <div class="row">
           ....
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion is perfectly fine to go with multiple container divs, i.e.

```
<section id="aboutus">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row>
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="another-div">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row>
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

etc

It makes for clean HTML, you apply your styling to the section backgrounds and you don't need to try and override the Bootstrap CSS.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is the out-of-the-box way of handling it.

There is a `.container-fluid` available which you could use to make your second example work, but it will have padding on the left and right, preventing a true full page background.

However, you could override that by adding something like `.container-fluid { padding:0; }` to a custom CSS file to eliminate that outside padding, though I am unsure what consequences that could have beyond just eliminating that edge. See http://www.bootply.com/nmcwmZfcgI for a working example.

In the end - though it is more verbose - I would go with example one. It keeps the outside padding built in, allowing your content to sit away from the outer edges of the browser without any additional CSS. See http://www.bootply.com/9Azdv2Jet2 for contrast to the first link.

#### Update

As another answer mentions, you can technically get away without the `.container` class at all. Would have the same effect as doing `.container-fluid` and zeroing out the padding.

Be aware, though, that the Bootstrap docs clearly say that it "requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system." You can probably remove it and be OK, but again, there could be unforeseen issues later on.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `div class="container"`

You can just do this:

```
<body>
     <section id="aboutus">
       <div class="row>
          ....
       </div>
     </section>

     <section id="section2">
       <div class="row>
          ....
       </div>
     </section>
</body>
```